# nan double in objective c

Tags: objective-c, double, division, nan, multiplication

I have this equation

`double x = ((newCount/allCount)/.8)*5.0;`

`newCount` is a double with value 0
`allCount` is a double with value 0

the result of `x` is `-nan(0x8000000000000)`

why this happens and how to check this value in **`objective c`** to assign default value for it

Comment: Could it be because you divide by zero? That rarely leaves a useful result beyond NaN.

Comment: @Henrik Beyond `NaN` _or_ plus/minus infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the denominator (`allCount`) is 0; dividing by zero is not allowed and the answer is not a number. The simplest thing you could do is to test for that before doing the division:

```
if (allCount != 0) {
  x = ((newCount/allCount)/.8)*5.0
} else {
  x = defaultValue;
}
```

There are more complicated ways using C's floating point environment and testing for the `FE_DIVBYZERO` exception, but while that's standard it's rarely used and therefore potentially more difficult for a later reader of the code to comprehend.

Answer (score 2):

You are [diving by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero). You can check for it using:

```
isnan(x)
```

Comment: More information on the `isnan()` function (and related stuff) on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/) or the [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/isnan.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

allCount is a 0, thus you just divided by 0 (which is impossible if you didn't know..)  So before you assign x, just make sure that allCount is not 0 first.

```
if (allCount != 0)
    double x = ((newCount/allCount)/.8)*5.0;
```